# Removing Sounds Invoked within a MovieClip from main Time Line

Tags: actionscript-3

I currently have a difficulty removing specific sounds from playing when I advance through the timeline on a particular project.

The user chooses a particular item on the timeline which will display a specific movieclip and will then play a specific sound on MOUSE_DOWN.

The eventListener for MOUSE_DOWN which exists as follows:

```
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, sprayWater);
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, stopWater);

function sprayWater(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    waterarm.gotoAndStop(2);
    trace("SPRAYING WATER");    
}

function stopWater(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    waterarm.water.gotoAndPlay("waterE");   
}
```

on frame 2 of 'waterarm' is a movieclip called 'water' that contains an animation of water and the following code to start the water sound:

```
var sfxWater:sfxwater;
var waterChannel:SoundChannel;
sfxWater = new sfxwater;
waterChannel = sfxWater.play();
```

on the frame "waterE" an animation of the water disappearing exists and the code `sfxWater.stop();`.

When the user progresses beyond this frame on the root timeline, the sound effect of water still remains on MOUSE_DOWN despite the movieclip no longer existing on the timeline at that point.

The ideal outcome will be the individual sound playing on MOUSE_DOWN and stopping on MOUSE_UP only when this movieclip is visible on the main timeline.  If anybody can provide any assistance in being able to prevent the sound from playing and removing this event listener (through code on the main timeline if possible) it would be greatly appreciated.

Regards,
Darren

Comment: Is there something wrong with:

function stopWater(event:MouseEvent):void {
    removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, sprayWater);
    removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, stopWater);
    waterarm.water.gotoAndPlay("waterE");   
}

Comment: thanks for your reply Michael.  I didn't state in my original post that the user doesn't move from this frame when they 'spray water', they should be able to press the button as many times as they like, there is collision detection on the root timeline which determines whether they progress elsewhere or stay on this frame when MOUSE_DOWN.

Comment: "flash gives me an array basically saying that 'sprayWater' doesn't exist." is that the function or a movieclip?

You might want to look into a custom dispatchEvent class or add a line in your mouse_down that says something like:

`if(movieclip){//if the movieclip exists
//do stuff
}`

I need to get used to the enterkey submitting comments...

Comment: sorry, that was a typo - array was meant to be error.
sprayWater is the function, but it still triggers when I hold the mouse button down . . .

Answer (score 1):

If stopping the sound is all that you want why not use `SoundMixer.stopAll()`.

You can use it in the MOUSE_UP event after checking if the said movieclip's `visible` property.

Comment: thanks for the reply loxxy. We have other sounds playing at the same time through their own sound channels and so the stopAll prevents them from continuing.

the other issue is that even by stopping the sound in this way, once I progress past this part of the timeline, the MOUSE_DOWN event is still being triggered even though the parent movieclip is no longer on the stage.

Comment: Try removing the event listener as soon as it's use is over. You can't have multiple sound channels playing & be tracking all using the same sound channel object. You probably need an array.

Comment: thanks loxxy.  I have several different sound channels; one for voice over, one for one type of sound effect and then this one.  they are all controlled separately and it 'has' been working well up until now.
I've been trying to remove the eventListener (preferably from within the collision detection code) flash gives me an array basically saying that 'sprayWater' doesn't exist.